# External hard drive troubleshooting

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I've got a 2TB WD Ext HDD that I'm guessing is starting to fail. The thing is that I currently have almost 2TB of data on there, and really don't want to lose some of it. It's been written and read from quite heavily, so this is expected. But the problem is that I'm not good at troubleshooting faulty drives.

The drive is reporting as not being partitioned and it's currently write protected so I can't do much with it.

The output of `mountvol`:

```
\\?\Volume{5454dbb5-3841-47a5-8871-75b03d7a7b44}\
    C:\

\\?\Volume{64ed472f-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
    D:\

\\?\Volume{a9d1eaa0-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
    E:\

\\?\Volume{454c5727-0000-0000-007e-000000000000}\
    F:\

\\?\Volume{411aaf7f-21b6-4605-a782-75b28e5ee4e7}\
    *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

\\?\Volume{970416d0-348e-11e6-953c-806e6f6e6963}\
    H:\
```

I can find the drive there, as the drive with `*** NO MOUNT POINTS ***` is the recovery partition for the OS, and the rest of the drives are working fine. I want to run `chkdsk` on the drive, but I can't find out how when I can't find any drive letter, mount point or volume name for the drive.

Here's a screenshot of the Disk Management utility, and the unallocated drive is the one I want to troubleshoot. The OS is in Swedish, but I'm happy to translate whatever you need to know.

[image: disk management utility]

Comment: click on the left side where the red icon is and do a rightlick and select "bring online"

Comment: Here's the right click http://i.imgur.com/QnHN1AZ.png, and this is the message that pops up when I click "Offline" http://i.imgur.com/Ztia2B8.png which translates to "Media is write-protected".

Comment: click on initialize disk. What happens here?

Comment: That's greyed out. Can't click it unfortunately.

Comment: how do you connect it? USB 2/3 or via eSATA?

Comment: USB 3, and the drive has been working for a very long time, but yesterday it started acting up and today it's "gone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've managed to solve this issue. I'm not an expert on this, so don't take my word for it, but it seems like the partition table was either missing or corrupted. So I donwloaded [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), extracted it, ran it, selected `Append log` and then selected my drive in the list.

```
Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 120 GB / 111 GiB
 Disk /dev/sdb - 240 GB / 223 GiB
 Disk /dev/sdc - 500 GB / 465 GiB
 Disk /dev/sdd - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB
 Drive C: - 119 GB / 111 GiB
 Drive D: - 240 GB / 223 GiB
 Drive E: - 500 GB / 465 GiB
 Drive F: - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB
```

In this case, it was `/dev/sdd`. Next up was selecting partition table type, and it hinted that it was a `Intel/PC Partition` so I went with that. After that I ran `Analyze`, then `Quick search`, set the partition to `Primary` (with the left & right arrow keys, the partition in the list turns green) and wrote the partition table to the disk. After that I restarted my computer and the drive is mounted and working fine.

Comment: You might want to check SMART for any underlying problems in that external hard drive.

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed it. You should do a backup of the data